# ACRA vs. Logback for Android?

Tags: android, exception, logging, logback, acra

I know ACRA CAN be used as an application Logger. 
Here's an example which I used from doc'n:

```
public class GAELapplication extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
ACRA.init(this);

SystemException  INITIALIZATION_LOG =  new SystemException ();
//Log the beginning of this app session in order to record ALL devices.
ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleSilentException(INITIALIZATION_LOG);
}}//application
```

My question: Since ACRA was designed to primarily log EXCEPTIONS, are there any downsides to using it ALSO as an application logger? I am currently using Logback for Android (which I love) but I'm beginning to love ACRA even more and considering replacing it and using ACRA exclusively.

Are there any downsides to using ACRA as an app logger instead of Logback?
Does anyone have any comments on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely not be using ACRA as an application logger.

It's not what it was designed for. You would end up streaming an ACRA report over the net for each "log message". While you could cut the message down to a minimal set, there are some field that are intrinsic to crash reporting that are always sent.